# Get UUID of / filesystem from script

Tags: command-line, scripts, partitioning, mountpoint, uuid

How can I get UUID of a volume that contains the `/` filesystem? 
The best thing for that I've found to date is `blkid -o list`. But this output is human readable and hard to parse. Maybe there is a better way?

I need that to parameterize configuration management with system-specific templates.

*NOTE about `blkid` gotcha for those who may reuse outcomes of my question in future: `blkid` caches results of previous runs at `/etc/blkid.tab` . That means that running `blkid` as non-root user first time will not return any data. Also, running `blkid` as non-root user after root run will return stale (possibly incorrect) data.*

Comment: On my own systems, I assign human readable, unique labels to all partitions. Then I can find out almost anything about them by using their labels and `/dev/disk/by-label`... This also works for partitions which are not mounted. It has the advantage of being able to write scripts which do things like rsync from root to root-bak which is far less error prone than using 2 UUIDS that don't "mean" anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`findmnt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/findmnt.8):

```
$ findmnt /        
TARGET SOURCE       FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/md127p1 ext4   rw,relatime,stripe=256,data=ordered
$ findmnt / -o UUID
UUID
046a554b-d9f5-4b23-82e6-ffaeb98284aa
$ findmnt / -o UUID -n
046a554b-d9f5-4b23-82e6-ffaeb98284aa
```

It also has several options to control how it looks up information, and how it presents it (including JSON output!). It's part of the `mount` package, so available on any Ubuntu installation.

Comment: This works great on 16.04. It failed to function for me on 14.04. I had to use [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/967353/225694) to obtain desired results on trusty.

Answer (score 12):

Another solution:

```
lsblk -nr -o UUID,MOUNTPOINT | grep -Po '.*(?= /$)'
```

- `-n` suppresses the header (not really needed, but safer for parsing)
- `-r` makes raw output (makes it safer to parse)
- `-o UUID,MOUNTPOINT` include only necessary information

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `lsblk` command to output the UUID, but you need the device name of the partition (such as /dev/sda2). You can get this by using the `df` command and trimming the output. Use command substitution to give the device name to `lsblk`. It appears you need sudo to access the UUID, although the normal output of lsblk does not require it:

```
sudo lsblk -n -o UUID "$(df -P / | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

Comment: This works for me without `sudo` on 16.04.

Comment: only if you (or some script) have ever ran this command as root before.  Also, the ouput may be stale (from cache) in this case

Comment: @Dmitriusan I ran this on a 14.04 system that has never had `lsblk` or `blkid` run by root and it worked perfectly. Do you know why there would be a caching issue with this command and not with the version posted by Rovo? Does the raw output circumvent caching in some way?

Comment: I think any command that accesses UUID of devices would require root access (including version posted by Rovo). Regarding lsblk, here is a related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210889/why-and-when-does-lsblk-require-sudo (see the first answer)

Comment: I agree that sudo is necessary, but can't find anything to suggest that lsblk relies on caching. Even if I run `blkid` as root, creating the cache file at `/dev/.blkid.tab`, non-sudo use of `lsblk` will not show anything from the UUID column. I don't think there's a risk of stale output.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I managed to come up with is

```
blkid -o list | awk '/\/[[:space:]]+/{ print $0 }' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

Feels like non-optimal, but works.

**Note:** [[:space:]] means <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: This works for me but with `sudo`.

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the value of `mountpoint` to the current mount point of the file system in question:

```sh
dev="$(exec awk -v mountpoint='/' '($2 == mountpoint){ print $1; quit; }' /proc/mounts)" &&
sudo blkid -o export -- "$dev" | sed -ne 's/^UUID=//p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```
sudo tune2fs -l $(df  / | tail -1 |awk '{print $1}') |grep UUID|awk '{ print $3 }'
```

tune2fs is in the e2fsprogs package, which I can't remember if it's installed by default.

```
sudo apt install e2fsprogs
```

if it isn't installed.

Comment: I get `awk: not an option: -e` I edited your answer to make it functional. If I've overstepped, please feel free to roll it back. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Strange, it seems to work with or without the -e for me. -e is documented in the man page for awk. I've always used it in scripts and I was surprised it worked fine without it :) I think -e is an old UNIX habit. But, I should have been consistent in my usage and used -e in either both places or neither place so as not to confuse people.

Comment: Ah, I get the same result as you under 14.04 which uses `gawk`. I get the error specified under 16.04 which appears to use `mawk` instead.

Comment: It's one of those /etc/alternatives things.  /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk for me on my 16.04. Mawk is installed, but not active in /etc/alternatives. On my 17.04 gnome it points to awk. On my fresh install 17.10 it's mawk. After installing gawk the link points to gawk, uninstalling gawk returns it to mawk.

Comment: :-) It's these minor differences between supposedly similar programs that likely led to statements like "Less is more"

Answer (score 1):

**Tested to work on 14.04 and 16.04**

A simple one-liner that should always produce the UUID of a the root `/` is

> export DRIVE=$(mount | grep ' / ' | awk -F" on " '{print $1}');blkid $DRIVE| cut -d '"' -f2
>   `

What we are doing here is grepping the output of mount to match the root symbol with spaces on either side `/` to avoid matching when `/` is used as a path extension symbol, piping that through `awk` using " on " as a field separator in order to output only the device name and assigning THAT to the environment variable $DRIVE, then using the output of `blkid $DRIVE` piped through cut using the `"` as a field separator and selecting only the second field which strips out everything else, leaving only the UUID.

**Note** that what belongs after grep in the above command is actually '<kbd>space</kbd>/<kbd>space</kbd>' and not '/' as it appears.

This has the benefit of not requiring `sudo` and will return the appropriate result regardless of how the drive is mounted.

It would be wise to insure that you aren't using the $DRIVE environment variable for anything else prior to attempting this approach `echo $DRIVE` will return  blank line if you aren't using the variable.